# Listing days between two dates

Tags: vba, excel, date, date-format

I am trying to write some code that will take two dates, and create a list of each day between those two dates. My code is this:

```
Sub DateList()

    Dim start As Date
    start = DateValue("1/1/2001")

    Dim finish As Date
    finish = DateValue("1/1/2002")

    Dim datearray()
    ReDim datearray(finish - start + 1)

    For i = 0 To finish - start
        datearray(i) = start + i
    Next

    Range("A1:A" & UBound(datearray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(datearray)

End Sub
```

However the result looks like this:

```
   1/01/2001
   1/02/2001
   1/03/2001
   1/04/2001
   1/05/2001
   1/06/2001
   1/07/2001
   1/08/2001
   1/09/2001
   1/10/2001
   1/11/2001
   1/12/2001
13/01/2001
14/01/2001
15/01/2001
16/01/2001
17/01/2001
18/01/2001
19/01/2001
20/01/2001
21/01/2001
22/01/2001
23/01/2001
24/01/2001
25/01/2001
26/01/2001
27/01/2001
28/01/2001
29/01/2001
30/01/2001
31/01/2001
   2/01/2001
   2/02/2001
   2/03/2001
      ....
```

You can see there's a problem when it gets to the 13th row. It seems like somewhere along the line there's a switch between `dd/mm/yyyy` formatting and `mm/dd/yyyy` formatting. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your computer's regional system uses some form DMY as its default date setting. Although Excel uses the computer's regional settings by default, VBA always uses the North American MDY. This is in order that code can be used by different regional areas without transcribing every form of coded date routine into the regional settings. There are some ways to get around VBA's EN-US-centric methods ([Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) comes to mind) but for all intents and purposes, if you code in VBA, you need to code in MDY.

If you widen column A sufficiently, you will see that the values from 13-Jan-2001 to 31-Jan-2001 are left aligned while the others are right aligned. This is the first hint that they are text values and not actual Dates (aka Numbers).

Forget about dates for a minute and think of the values as a series of long integers starting at 36,892 and going to 37,257.

```
Sub DateList()
    Dim start As Long, finish As Long
    Dim datearray As Variant, i As Long

    start = CLng(DateValue("1/1/2001"))
    finish = CLng(DateValue("1/1/2002"))

    ReDim datearray(finish - start + 1)

    For i = 0 To finish - start
        datearray(i) = start + i
    Next

    Range("A1:A" & UBound(datearray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(datearray)
    Range("A1:A" & UBound(datearray) + 1).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
End Sub
```

Remember that the raw underlying value of a date (i.e. [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx)) is simply the number of days since 31-Dec-1899. How you display it on the worksheet may default to the user's regional settings but you can display them any way you see fit.

[image: DMY vs MDY]

Hint: In Date style number formats, there are two number formats that start with an asterisk. In a workbook distributed amongst computers with various regional settings, these will change to whichever MDY or DYM that the resident computer is running under.

More on VBA coding for DMY/MDY at [Convert String to Date VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805453/convert-string-to-date-vba/31805582#31805582).

Answer (score 2):

Add this line as the last line of your procedure:

```
    Range(A:A).NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy"
```

...or set the range to whichever date format you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the input @ExcelHero, but it doesn't solve the issue. If you look at the difference between the 12th and 13th row, you'll see that cell A12 is 1st of Dec 2001 (I wanted 12th of Jan 2001) and then A13 is "13/1/2001", which is not recognised as a date at all.

Comment: Are you using the American version of Excel, or another localized version like the UK?