# vbscript assign date variable to .xls cell with UK date

Tags: excel, date, vbscript

Struggling to find an answer to this one. To cut a long story short, I work in a case management system that is developed in it's own syntax, although can execute VBScript through a native command. I have written code in VBS to export some data from the system to a template xls file but I am having trouble with a date value being assigned to a cell with a custom type format of dd-mmm-yy. The value passed through is in standard UK format (e.g. 08/01/2016) in a variable ("DATE_OF_INST") and assigned to the cell using:

```
cell.Value = DATE_OF_INST
```

and at this point the date seems to be interpreted in US format and becomes 01-Aug-16, not 08-Jan-16. I have tried switching local format to True in Workbook.Open and Workbook.SaveAs commands but this has no effect. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: The variable must be text because while VBA is very US-EN centric, a raw date of 08-Jan-2016 is still only 42377 to a computer. This has always been a problem with mucking about with DMY vs MDY in any language. Use the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) if you can. This will be 42377 regardless of regional setting if it is in fact a date and not text-that-looks-like-a-date. Apply a cell [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) after the values has been transferred.

Comment: `Excel`'s `VBA` will always use EN_US locale. But the `C` - converting functions (`CStr`, `CDbl`, `CDate`, ...) will use the operating system's locale settings. So try `cell.Value = CDate(DATE_OF_INST)`.

Comment: @AxelRichter. CDate throws a type mismatch.

Comment: @Jeeped. The data passed is a string in UK format DD/MM/YYYY. I assume this needs converting to an integer representation then have the NumberFormat property set when the value is assigned to the cell? If so, can you advise how to convert the variable to the integer representation you have mentioned? Thanks

Comment: @Jeeped. Apologies, I was using CDate in the wrong content. I have passed the system string variable (    LF13) and assigned it to the local variable with CDate conversion:

    DATE_OF_INST = CDate(LF13)

this has worked.

Comment: Would this be a continuation of [Convert String to Date VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805453/convert-string-to-date-vba/31805582#31805582)?

Comment: @Jeeped. Yes, only a without the timestamp element and using VBS not VBA as the command is run natively,

Comment: @AxelRichter - I would say that they **try** to use regional settings but in the event of an ambiguous date, they revert to EN-US. e.g. they will correctly interpret 25/12/2015 and not throw an error but 7/4/16 is still 04-Jul-2016 and not 07-Apr-2016 in a DMY regional setting.

Comment: OK, I won't mark this as a duplicate then. Perhaps someone could gather an answer from these comments ...?

Comment: @Jeeped. To summarize; Using VBS to pass a UK format (DD/MM/YYYY) date as a string to Custom Type cell, the system date conversion will use EN-US format. To resolve this, assign the string value to a local variable and use CDate to convert and define the data type before passing the value to cell.Value

Comment: For the benefit of future readers this was achieved by passing the date value through the "Fields" parameter in the "&Script" command in "VisualFiles" (Case Management System). @Jeeped It may be worth creating a VisualFiles tag?