# Invert day and month from a date value if condition is met

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have the following two date columns in Excel:

```
A                       B
DD-MM-YYYY              DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM
```

If the day value and the month value of those two columns don't match, and the month of the B column matches the day of the A column and the day of the B column matches the month of the A column, then I have to invert the day and month values of the B column.

For example, if I have:

```
A                        B
04-10-2016               10-04-2016 22:10
```

I need that VBA turns it into:

```
A                        B
04-10-2016               04-10-2016 22:10
```

I would do something like:

```
For j=1 to Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
   If ExtractDate(Cells(j, 2)) <> Cells(j, 1) And ExtractMonth(Cells(j, 2)) = ExtractDay(Cells(j, 1) And ExtractDay(Cells(j, 2)) = ExtractMonth(Cells(j, 1) Then
   InvertDayAndMonth(Cells(j, 2)
   End if
Next j
```

I know that those functions don't exist, can someone help me out with that?

Comment: I would suggest importing the dates properly to start off with. DMY vs MDY issues are a headache. 27/04/2016 will come ion as text because it cannot be resolved but 07/04/2016 will become 04-Jul-2016 because it will be resolved wrong. See [Convert String to Date VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805453/convert-string-to-date-vba/31805582?s=1|0.0000#31805582)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve it:

```
For j = 3 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

If Day(Cells(j, 2).Value) = Month(Cells(j, 3).Value) And Month(Cells(j, 2).Value) = Day(Cells(j, 3).Value) Then
    d = Cells(j, 3).Value
    Cells(j, 3) = DateSerial(Year(d), Day(d), Month(d)) + TimeSerial(Hour(d), Minute(d), Second(d))
End If

Next j
```

Answer (score 0):

No real need to perform a check. If the date in column A is guaranteed accurate, then all you need from column B is the time part.

Extract the time part from column B and add that to the date part of column A. Put the result where you need it.